# macOS X11 forwarding error

Tags: macos, xorg, x11-forwarding, xquartz

I need to forward display one of software run from Linux computer (Debian 4.19) to my Mac computer (macOS 10.14.6 Mojave). I use XQuartz 2.7.11. The software 'freeze' once displayed and on terminal shown error messages:

> libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
>
> libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
>
> X Error: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation) 2
>
> Extension:    149 (Uknown extension)
>
> Minor opcode: 3 (Unknown request)
>
> Resource id:  0x0

Any suggestion to fix this?